# Convert anchor text in url part - preg_replace, regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I guess my question is very simple, but I am new to php so I'm lost with this. Basically I would like to replace blanks (" ") by dashes ("-") and let the anchor text in lowercase, since it will be used as part of the url.

Ex: the anchor text "William Shakespeare" will be converted to "william-shakespeare" to be inserted as part of the url.

```
<a href="http://site.com/biography/william-shakespeare">William Shakespeare</a>
```

If the text has only one word will be transformed to lowercase
Ex: "Shakespeare" will just be converted to "shakespeare".

```
<a href="http://site.com/tag/shakespeare">Shakespeare</a>
```

*Note: Text translated from the Portuguese language using GoogleTranslate.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a regex. Just use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) & [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php):

```
strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $string));
```

You should probably also [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it, in case you have some wonky characters in there:

```
urlencode( strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $string)) );
```